# Is the Sony A6400 weaker than the Pixel 4a?

Tags: sharpness, comparison

I've just bought a returnable Sony A6400. I've taken some shots with it, and the same shots with my Pixel 4a. (Static subject; lighting not bright, but nowhere near night mode.) A6400 set to JPEG Extra Fine, Image Size L:24M, Aspect Ratio 3x2, ISO Auto.

In each case the Pixel 4a's shot is noticeably clearer than its A6400 mate.

What's your conjecture: Am I doing something wrong, and if so what do you think it might be; or is it time to return the Sony? I realize the 6400 has lots of  extra features, but simple picture clarity seems like table stakes.

EDIT SAT SEP 11/21:  Thank you to responders. I'm currently traveling, but when I get back to where the a6400 is I'll post comparison shots, with associated metadata and camera settings, as you've reasonably requested. This should be around Sept 25.

SECOND EDIT SEP 21/21: My attempt to post samples. Haven't done this before so probably messing it up. Critiques of posting technique will be as welcome as those of photo pairs.

Note that the Pixel 4a made its own decisions, and I used the A6400 on Auto with the 16-50mm kit lens; so none of the settings was deliberately chosen.

**THIRD EDIT OCT 10/21:**
**The responses have been helpful. To quote a couple:**

- **Photo[s] on smartphones are typically over-processed to look good, while photos from advanced cameras look pretty bland because they are minimally post-processed in-camera by default (so that they can be post-processed later).**
- **The photos out of the Sony camera might not look as great right out of the camera - but because they aren't as heavily processed, you can do a lot more work with them after the fact to get the exact look you want than you can with an already processed image out of the phone.**

**As it happens, I'm not looking to spend time making adjustments after shooting, aside from cropping. So for my particular kind of usage it does seem plausible that a good phone camera will give the stronger results, and I've returned the A6400. Thanks for helping me get clarity on this.**

Books Pixel 4a: f/1.73  1/24  ISO85
[image: Books Pixel 4a]
Books Sony A6400: F/3.5  1/160  ISO2500
[image: Books Sony A6400]

Beasts Pixel 4a: f/1.73  1/24  ISO100
Don't know why it's smaller than the Sony, which was taken with more pixels. Something about the reduction to 2M for posting, perhaps?  As mentioned above, I'm new to all this. At any rate, the Pixel does NOT get fuzzier when expanded to the size of the Sony.

[image: Beasts Pixel 4a]

Beasts Sony A6400: f/3.5  1/160  ISO3200
[image: Beasts Sony A6400]

Toys Pixel 4a: f/173  1/24  ISO50
[image: Toys Pixel 4a]
Toys Sony A6400:  f/4  1/160  ISO1250
[image: Toys Sony A6400]

Comment: What lens are you using and what aperture? Pixel 4a has f/1.7 which lets a lot of light to the relatively small sensor (crop factor 6.2). The light on the A6400 sensor depends on lens aperture, but its crop factor is 1.53.

Comment: Was the A6400 in auto mode?

Comment: What do you mean by "clearer"? Photo on smartphones are typically over-processed to look good, while photos from advanced cameras look pretty bland because they are minimally post-processed in-camera by default (so that they can be post-processed later).

Comment: @xenoid That looks a lot like an answer (which I'd upvote if it was fleshed out just a bit) to me.

Comment: @MichaleC The question would need to be fleshed out a bit too (example pictures)

Comment: I'd like to know why you bought the Sony camera. You don't say what you want to use the camera for. You don't say what lens(es) you have available - I'm going to assume you only have the kit lens. There are much better lenses available, especially when it comes to telephoto options. It's also not clear to me that you understand depth of field and the effect of aperture. Maybe what you call "unclear" is just parts of the photo that aren't in focus. Phone cameras are great, but interchangeable-lens dedicated cameras are still much more flexible, with ergonomics more comfortable for taking photos

Comment: If good out of camera results are your goal: Experiment with the "creative style" options as well as the contrast/saturation/sharpness sliders. Usually, on Sony, "Vivid" and "Clear" are good base settings for SOOC without becoming too overprocessed looking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm far from a photography expert, but to me the beasts one looks better in the sony picture - at least if the tiger is the star of the show. He's perfectly in focus, with everything else nicely blurred.  I'm guessing that the automatic eye focus locked onto the tiger and focused there. That's why the tiger's face is so clear compared to the rest of the picture.

For the rest it's hard to tell - the photos got pretty heavily recompressed when they were uploaded.

The biggest difference is going to be that your phone does a lot of post processing to make the image look better. It's got a lot of "AI" features that make decisions for you that usually result in a decent picture under pretty much any conditions.

The photos out of the sony camera might not look as great right out of the camera - but because they aren't as heavily processed, you can do a lot more work with them after the fact to get the exact look you want than you can with an already processed image out of the phone.

When using purely automatic modes and doing no post processing, phone cameras can surpass what you can get out of a DSLR a lot of the time these days. But if you do some post processing, you'll usually get better shots out of a DSLR even in automatic mode, and once you learn how to adjust some of the parameters manually, you can get even better shots that wouldn't work well from a phone camera.